# Bounding box coordinates prediction

Tags: computer-vision, opencv

How to pass multiple bounding boxes coordinates to CNN model?My goal is to predict the coordinates of texts in an image.

Answer (score -1):

Please look into the Mask R-CNN (Faster CNN)
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/